# Other alternatives for date/timestamp during delta-import

Tags: solr, data-import

For Performing delta-update in Solr, last_index_time (which is stored in dataimport.properties) is compared with a date/timestamp column in Database.

Is it possible to configure in Solr so that:

> - we use some other column (say an **'id' which increases sequentially**)    from Database instead of date/timestamp ?
> - **last_index_id** is stored in    dataimport.properties instead of last_index_time ?
> - during delta-import    we may use a condition like **'where id > dataimporter.last_index_id'** ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

I believe your use case is where you have an append-only table with an auto-increment primary key. Solr DIH does not seem to support what you want. (Try asking the Solr user mailing list though.)

But there is an alternate approach you can try using the idea from the example given in Solr Wiki [DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport). If you can pass the largest `id` in your Solr index as a parameter to the import request, then you can use that in your data import query.

For this you need to first issue a query to Solr to fetch the largest id:

```
q=*:*&sort=id desc&rows=1&fl=id
```

Call this `MAXID`. Then when you call your full-import pass this id like:

```
/dataimport?command=full-import&id=MAXID
```

You can get the id request param in your data-config using `${dataimporter.request.id}`.
In your data-config.xml your query should be like:

```
<entity name="item" 
        pk="id"
        query="SELECT id, name FROM item 
                 WHERE id > '${dataimporter.request.id}'">
```

Of course, for doing a complete re-index of all your documents, you will pass `id=0`, assuming 0 is the minimum key value you got.

Haven't tried this myself, but you can experiment and tell what you find.

(With all this said, it is obviously very easy to add a timestamp column to your table. If you are using MySQL, you can just keep the timestamp column as `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and not even bother to update it yourself.)

Comment: Nice thoughts! I completely agree that "timestamp" is the best option, as we could handle updations as well. Was just looking for alternatives! Thanks anyway!